Lark parser issues with tokenizing priority
I'm having some trouble parsing an input. Below is the offending snippet:
?start: forstmt

forstmt: "for" ID "in" range FOO  -> forstmt

?range: "[" atom DOTDOT atom "]" -> rangetuple

DOTDOT.2: ".."

?atom: NUM            -> num

%import common.NUMBER -> NUM
%import common.WS
%ignore WS

When I input something like for i in [1..10] print(i), I expect a tokenization similar to:
[ 1 .. 10 ]
But even with assigning the center dots their own named terminal, and assigning that a higher priority than the numbers, it still seems to always parse as:
[ 1. .10 ]
I've tried changing the terminal priority, I've tried changing the rule priority under the earley parser, and I've tried running the earley parser with ambiguity='explicit', all with no change to the current erroneous output.
Here's the error I get when running with parser(grammar, parser='lalr'):
Unexpected token Token('NUM', '.10') at line 1, column 13.
Expected one of: 
        * DOTDOT
        * MINUS
        * STAR
        * SLASH
        * PLUS
Previous tokens: [Token('NUM', '1.')]

...and here is the full grammar I'm using in case I omitted something important.
?start: stmtlist

?stmtlist: stmt (";" stmt?)* -> stmtlist

stmt: "var" ID "=" expr         -> decl
    | ID "=" expr               -> assign
    | "if" "(" expr ")" stmt ("else" stmt)? -> ifstmt
    | "while" "(" expr ")" stmt -> whstmt
    | "for" ID "in" range stmt  -> forstmt
    | "print" "(" expr ")"      -> prstmt
    | "{" stmtlist "}"          -> block

?range: "[" expr DOTDOT expr "]" -> rangetuple

DOTDOT.2: ".."

?expr: expr "+" term  -> add
    |  expr "-" term  -> sub
    |  term

?term: term "*" atom  -> mul
    |  term "/" atom  -> div
    |  atom

?atom: "(" expr ")"
    |  ID             -> var
    |  NUM            -> num

  %import common.CNAME  -> ID
  %import common.NUMBER -> NUM
  %import common.WS
  %ignore WS

Also, I am aware that using integers instead of all numeric input types for NUM resolves the issue, I was just hoping to not be so restrictive with the grammar if at all possible. I also know that having real number values in a range parameter is nonsense, but I'm hoping to accept expressions like i+3 in the range value, which can reuse my functions which can accept floats. I was hoping to do the type checking for the range domain in the rangetuple function; it makes more sense to me to be able to reuse my functions and just do my type guarding/error checking in the functions using the expressions.
Minimum reproducible example:
Lark: 1.1.9
Python: 3.12.3
import sys
from lark import Lark, v_args
from lark.visitors import Interpreter
from typing import Any

grammar = """
?start: stmtlist

?stmtlist: stmt? (";" stmt?)* -> stmtlist

stmt: "for" ID "in" range stmt  -> forstmt
    | "print" "(" expr ")"      -> prstmt
    | "{" stmtlist "}"          -> block

?range: "[" expr ".." expr "]" -> rangetuple

?expr: ID             -> var
    |  NUM            -> num

%import common.CNAME  -> ID
%import common.NUMBER -> NUM
%import common.WS
%ignore WS
"""

parser = Lark(grammar)


class Env():
    '''Keeps track of variables and manages scopes for those variables.'''

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        # initializes with one scope open by default; global scope
        self._scopes: list[dict] = [dict()]

    def extend(self, x: str, val: Any | None = None) -> None:
        '''Declares `x` as a variable in the
        current scope, with `x = val`.'''
        location = self._findScope(x)
        # variable is undefined or has not been declared in current scope
        if (location is None) or (location != (len(self._scopes) - 1)):
            self._scopes[-1][x] = val
        # variable is defined in current scope
        else:
            raise NameError(f'{x} was redeclared', name=x)

    def update(self, x: str, val: Any) -> None:
        '''Assigns `val` to current visible `x`.'''
        location = self._findScope(x)

        if location is not None:
            self._scopes[location][x] = val  # overwrite nearest x
        else:
            raise NameError(f'{x} is undefined', name=x)

    def _findScope(self, x) -> int | None:
        '''Return the scope index that `x` exists in, if any.
        Returns index in order by environment recency.'''
        for index in range(len(self._scopes)-1, -1, -1):
            if x in self._scopes[index]:
                return index

        return None

    def lookup(self, x: str) -> Any:
        '''returns `x`'s value from the most recently assigned scope.'''
        location = self._findScope(x)

        if location is not None:
            return self._scopes[location][x]
        else:
            raise NameError(f"{x} is undefined", name=x)

    def openScope(self) -> None:
        '''Increases variable stack height.'''
        self._scopes.append(dict())

    def closeScope(self) -> None:
        '''Decreases variable stack height.'''
        if len(self._scopes) >= 1:
            del self._scopes[-1]
        else:
            raise IndexError("attempted to close scope when none were open")


@v_args(inline=True)
class Eval(Interpreter):
    def __init__(self, env: Env | None = None):
        super().__init__()
        # if no environment is supplied, it will rely on its own
        self.env = env if env is not None else Env()

    def num(self, val) -> int | float:
        for char in ".e":  # signifiers for float
            if char in val:
                return float(val)

        return int(val)

    def var(self, var: str) -> int | float:
        return self.env.lookup(var)

    def block(self, statements) -> None:
        self.env.openScope()
        self.visit(statements)
        self.env.closeScope()

    def stmtlist(self, *statements) -> None:
        for statement in statements:
            self.visit(statement)

    def forstmt(self, id, rangetuple, stmt) -> None:
        self.env.openScope()
        self.env.extend(id)
        for i in range(*self.visit(rangetuple)):
            self.env.update(id, i)
            self.visit(stmt)
        self.env.closeScope()

    def rangetuple(self, expr1, expr2) -> tuple[int, int]:
        return (self.visit(expr1), self.visit(expr2))


def main():
    try:
        prog = sys.stdin.read()
        tree = parser.parse(prog)
        Eval().visit(tree)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

and I'm piping this file to stdin as input:
for i in [1..3] print(i)

results in:
No terminal matches '.' in the current parser context, at line 1 col 13

for i in [1..3] print(i)
            ^
Expected one of: 
        * __ANON_0

And changing the parsers used yields similar results.

Post a [mre] with debugging details. Your grammar works fine in my Linux machine with Python 3.11.6 and Lark 1.2.2.

@relent95 I've updated the post with a minimal reproducible example, as well as a solution that someone in my circle introduced me to. I'm open to better alternative solutions as well, though.

Please post the solution as an answer, not as part of the question.

You should try using the lexer="dynamic_complete" feature. Also you can modify the NUMBER regex and add a negative lookahead for .

Most scanner(lexer) implementations including one in Lark are context-free. It means the scanner matches "1..3" as a sequence of a number "1." and an invalid character ".", instead of matching it as a sequence of "1", "..", and "3" by looking back(backtracking) when the scanner finds an invalid character.
So, you can't do what you want. I recommend you define your specification saying the user should avoid such an ambiguous code, such as by writing "1 .. 3" instead of "1..3".

Right, that makes sense. I had a "solution" involving backtracking by using a lexer that supports that, but it's semantically invalid for a context-free grammar. This here is the correct answer.
